# How to know if the user leaves the route in Xamarin Google API. C#

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a app that uses the Maps API, and i have to recognize if the user leaves the route displayed in phone, i have this function.

```
public bool IsLocationOnEdge(IList<PositionMap> path, Location point, int tolerance = 100)
        {
            var C = new GeoCoordinate(point.Latitude, point.Longitude);
            for (int i = 0; i < path.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                var A = new GeoCoordinate(path[i].Latitude, path[i].Longitude);
                var B = new GeoCoordinate(path[i + 1].Latitude, path[i + 1].Longitude);

                var a = A.GetDistanceTo(B);
                var b = A.GetDistanceTo(C);
                var c = B.GetDistanceTo(C);

                var dist = b + c;
                double whatpartofpath = dist - a;
                
                var s = (a + b + c) / 2;
                var distance = 2 * Math.Sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c)) / a;
                if (distance < tolerance && whatpartofpath < tolerance)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
```

After testing the function, it seems to me to have some errors, which leads to calculation errors in the distance traveled. I would like to know if there is any way to improve it, or if anyone knows a way to use the maps library that does this job.

Comment: "have some errors" - please be more specific

Comment: I use this function to recognize if the user leaves the route, and if it leaves I mark a waypoint to use in calculating the distance traveled, but apparently it is returning that the user left the route when he is on it, I would just like to know if there is anything more precise to do this recognition.

Comment: Do you have sample input values that demonstrate the "wrong" behavior?

Comment: I only have the comparison of the value measured in the app with the value measured in the vehicle, which is giving a difference of 10% to 20%.

Comment: "value measured in vehicle" - what is that?  If you want general advice on an algorithm to calculate distance from a path, then I'd try https://gis.stackexchange.com/